# gnu screen title cannot be configured

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

I use `shelltitle` command in the `.screenrc`, but no matter what I set it, the new windows created are always having a default title, in the form of shell prompt, `user@hostname:cwd`, what is wrong with this config?